# PhoneGap with Android-SDK 4.4

Tags: cordova, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm running `npm phonegap -g` following [this tutorial](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide). Everything is fine, but when I run:

```
>cordova platform add android
>phonegap build android
```

I get this error:

```
[error] Please install Android target 17 (the Android 4.2 SDK). Make sure you
have the latest Android tools installed as well. Run `android` from your comman
d-line to install/update any missing SDKs or tools.
```

The Android SDK [site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) is using Android 4.4 and API lvl Android 19.

How can I update NPM, PhoneGap, and Cordova to use the latest version of Android?

Answer (score 6):

It's a cordova bug.

1- Replace `android-17` for `android-19` in android_parser.js file within the cordova module inside npm_modules of your node install.

2- Replace `android-17` for `android-19` in project.properties in your project.

Not a solution, just a workaround until Cordova release a fixed version.

Comment: The bug seems not hard-coded any more, but still persists: `Error: Please install Android target 18 (the Android newest SDK). Make sure you have the latest Android tools installed as well. Run "android" from your comman
d-line to install/update any missing SDKs or tools.`

Comment: It is fixed by now. If you do `cordova platform remove android` and then `cordova platform add android`it should take the latest API version found among your installed ones. Anyone knows how can be this configured?

Comment: I test and works well. remember if you start create cordova platform add using step `1`

Answer (score 4):

Change the  value of "target" key in `C:\Users\UserName\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\framework\project.properties` to "android-20", this way:

```
target=android-20
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. On phonegap 3.5 and switched to android-20

Answer (score 3):

@GermanDZ, not the project.properties in your project, but this file: C:\Users\USER_NAME.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.1.0\framework\project.properties

Comment: God bless you man, you saved me from my angry boss, in my case android 20

Answer (score 0):

hey just install Android 4.3(18) and try again..It works..

Answer (score 0):

You can update to the latest version like this:

- NPM: `sudo npm update -g npm`
- PhoneGap: `sudo npm update -g phonegap`
- Cordova: (no need to update Cordova if you are using PhoneGap: PhoneGap is build over Cordova)
- Android SDK: depending on how you installed it, if you did it through brew: `brew update android-sdk`

Then run a`android`, and download the latest API.

Then PhoneGap will use the latest API by default when running `phonegap build android`.

If you need to update a current project, run inside the project folder:

```
phonegap platform update android
```

And now if you run `build` again, it should use the latest version.